# How to I add contents from one object to another?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two objects, one has more content then the other

```
let obj1 = [
{title: 'title one'},
{title: 'title four'}
]

let obj2 = [
{title: 'title one', img:'..'},
{title: 'title two', img:'..'},
{title: 'title three', img:'..'},
{title: 'title four', img:'..'}
]
```

I want to be able to merge those two objects so that I get something like this

```
let newObject = [
{title: 'title one', img:'..'},
{title: 'title four', img:'..'}
]
```

Basically get all the objects within `obj2` that match the object of `obj1`

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: you didnt think there might already be an answer to this question on Stack Overflow already? Why do you even need the first array if the second array containes the first yet has extra information?

Comment: it seems you want an array which is the result of filtering obj2, based on the existence of an object in obj1 that has the same title ... in other words `let newObject = obj2.filter(({title}) => obj1.find(({title:target}) => target === title));`

Comment: @JaromandaX My mistake!

Comment: of course, that may not be the most efficient way of doing it ... there's also `let keys = obj1.map(({title}) => title), newObject = obj2.filter(({title}) => keys.includes(title));`

Comment: @Craicerjack The content is auto-generate - by gatsby. Then I am trying to filter posts by a keyword and add more content to it in the process, but explaining all that would take forever and completely hide the point that all I need would be to filter `obj2` to match the title from `obj1`. And there isn't a question already.

Comment: `.filter()` the array you want to parse based on the keyword and return a new array with the objects that contain the keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get all the elements from obj2 which are also present in obj1

```
   obj1.forEach((ele)=>{objInObj1AndObj2[ele.title]=1}); newObject = obj2.filter((ele)=>{return objInObj1AndObj2[ele.title] })
```

Answer (score -1):

Try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) example to start.

```
const object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

const object2 = Object.assign({c: 4, d: 5}, object1);

console.log(object2.c, object2.d);
// expected output: 3 5
```

Good luck!